# Wordpress Visual Composer Strech Row and Direction RTL

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, visual-composer

When I try to strech row in the row settings in Visual Composer, the row streches, but the position of the row is all wrong.
It happens only when body direction has `direction:rtl` css setting.

Website is online: http://ono.devurl.net/?page_id=871

Any way of fixing that?

Yuval.[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yuval Hey !

Try this script to fix your problem.

```js
    if( jQuery('html').attr('dir') == 'rtl' ){
        jQuery('[data-vc-full-width="true"]').each( function(i,v){
            jQuery(this).css('right' , jQuery(this).css('left') ).css( 'left' , 'auto');
        });
    }
```

Put this script code in jQuery(window).load.

hope this'll help you :)

Comment: great, but there is still a problem on resize :(

Answer (score 4):

Could be easier to resolve it with css, and it will work when page is resized too. 
Find a class for row before [data-vc-full-width="true"] and add such css to your rtl.css

```
.before-fullwidth-row {
    direction: ltr;
}
.before-fullwidth-row > div {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Seems to work...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix VC Row also on `window resize` use this solution:

```
    $(window).on( 'resize', function() {
        $( '.rtl [data-vc-full-width="true"]' ).each( function(){
            $( this ).css( 'right' , $( this ).css( 'left' ) ).css( 'left' , 'auto' );
        });
    }).resize();
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress Visual Composer full width row ( stretche row ) fix for RTL

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

function bs_fix_vc_full_width_row(){
    var $elements = jQuery('[data-vc-full-width="true"]');
    jQuery.each($elements, function () {
        var $el = jQuery(this);
        $el.css('right', $el.css('left')).css('left', '');
    });
}

// Fixes rows in RTL
jQuery(document).on('vc-full-width-row', function () {
    bs_fix_vc_full_width_row();
});

// Run one time because it was not firing in Mac/Firefox and Windows/Edge some times
bs_fix_vc_full_width_row();
});
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/aliaghdam/414d6e7f916c056a121a98ba64d0b7c0#file-visual-composer-rtl-fix-js)